# props don't have the right data in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

i use a firebase database and i take data from this base into JSON format. With this data i am using map function and i want to render my data into other components. My code is as shown below. The first component

```
function Products() { 

const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncCall() {
        const myurl = await axios.get("i put a example link here:mydata.json")
            setUrl(myurl.data)
    }
    asyncCall();

},[]);

return (
    <Row>
        {url.map((url => (
                <Col key={url.id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Bags url={url} />
                </Col>    
                )
        ))}
    </Row>
)
}
```

The second component that i want to render my data

```
function Bags(props) { 
return (

    <Row>
        <CardDeck>
            <Col sm={14} md={8} lg={6}>
                <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
                    {
                    props.url ? (
                        <div>
                            <Card.Img variant="top" src={ props.url.img || 'holder.js/100px160'} />
                            <Card.Body>
                                <Card.Title> {props.url.name} </Card.Title>
                                <Card.Text>
                                This is the greatest albums of rock band Pearl Jam according to Nikolas
                                </Card.Text>
                            </Card.Body>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="myprogress">
                            <CircularProgress color="secondary" />
                        </div>
                        )
                    }

                </Card>
            </Col>
        </CardDeck>
    </Row>
    
                       
)

}
```

With the second component i want to produce the number of Bootstrap-React Cards depending of the number of data i have. For example if i have 6 elements into my JSON file i want in the second component to produce 6 react-bootstrap Cards and print for each some informations like the name.
With the above code i accomplished to pass the props but the props that i console.log is not my data. This is what i get in my console when i

```
console.log(props)
```

[image]

Can anyone tell how i can pass my data correctly or suggest a better way to do that.
I hope my question is understood. I can give more information i anyone wants

Comment: does `props.url.name` render properly?

Comment: when i console.log(props.url.name) i get "props.url is undefined"

Comment: console.log(props.url) returns which value ?

Comment: this return "undefined" so this is why i see only my spinner in the screen

Comment: is `myurl.data` defined?

Comment: in my first component i assume. I console.log(myurl.data) and nothing show up in my console from this component.

Comment: can you add ```const myUrlJson = myurl.json(); console.log(myUrlJson);``` ??

Comment: You're not getting data from the response it looks like.

Comment: i assume that you mean this https://prnt.sc/vq4stq. Nothing show up in my console https://prnt.sc/vq4taw

Comment: @MatthewMoran you mean that i did not get data from firebase??

Comment: @MatthewMoran when i am doing this https://prnt.sc/vq4u5e my data console correct. But because i want to generate Cards i decide to go with the code i describe above

Comment: If the response is supposed to have a `data` property on it and you console.log it, and nothing shows up, then nothing is going to show up in the UI. You need to figure out what's going on with your request.

Comment: no, add this ```const myUrlJson = myurl.json(); console.log(myUrlJson);``` just after the ```const myurl = ....```

Comment: @Versifiction i do this https://prnt.sc/vq4wow nothing shown up in my console

Comment: I made an answer, it works

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
function Products() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncCall() {
      const myurl = await axios.get("i put a example link here:mydata.json");
      setUrl(myurl.data);
    }
    asyncCall();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Row>
      {/*{ {url.map((url => (  */}
      {/* the url in the arrow function was shadowing the url array that you were trying to pass to the bags componenet */}
      <Col key={url.id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
        <Bags url={url} />
      </Col>

      {/*           )
        ))}  */}
    </Row>
  );
}

function Bags(props) {
  return (
    <Row>
      <CardDeck>
        <Col sm={14} md={8} lg={6}>
          <Card className="my-3 p-3 rounded">
            {props.url.length > 0 ? (
              props.url.map((el) => (
                <div>
                  <Card.Img
                    variant="top"
                    src={el.img || "holder.js/100px160"}
                  />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title> {el.name} </Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                      This is the greatest albums of rock band Pearl Jam
                      according to Nikolas
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                </div>
              ))
            ) : (
              <div className="myprogress">
                <CircularProgress color="secondary" />
              </div>
            )}
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </CardDeck>
    </Row>
  );
}
```

can you please confirm the results?

Comment: Thank for your answer, with this i get that props.url is undefined https://prnt.sc/vq512g

Comment: can you please do `console.log(url)` right after `setUrl(myurl.data);` in `asyncCall`?

Comment: as i said above for some reason console.log from product.js (first component) are not show up in my console, so i did not get anything

Comment: but when i do this in my second component and don't use the first component https://prnt.sc/vq57pj i get my data from firebase correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me if it works

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncCall() {
      const response = await fetch(
        "https://mysiteproject-8adcf.firebaseio.com/products.json"
      );
      const responseJson = await response.json();
      console.log(responseJson);
      setUrl(responseJson);
    }
    asyncCall();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {url.map((url => (
                <Col key={url.id} sm={12} md={6} lg={4} xl={3}>
                    <Bags url={url} />
                </Col>    
                )
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't know why console.log from product.js (first component) are not show up in my console. This is not working for me in screen i see the spinner again

Answer (score 0):

I almost solved the problem with this implementation

```
function Bags() { 

const [url, setUrl] = useState([]);
//const [myfinal,setFinal] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function asyncCall() {
        const myurl = await axios.get("https://mysiteproject-8adcf.firebaseio.com/products.json")
            setUrl(myurl.data)
    }
    asyncCall();

},[]);

if (url) {
    //let myvar = url;
    //console.log(myvar.img);
    //console.log(myvar);
    url.map((url) => console.log(url.img));
}

//console.log()

return (

    <Row>
        <CardDeck>
            <Col sm={14} md={8} lg={6}>
                <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
                {url.length > 0 ? (
          url.map((el) => (
            <div>
              <Card.Img
                variant="top"
                src={el.img || "holder.js/100px160"}
              />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title> {el.name} </Card.Title>
                <Card.Text>
                  This is the greatest albums of rock band Pearl Jam
                  according to Nikolas
                </Card.Text>
              </Card.Body>
            </div>
          ))
        ) : (
          <div className="myprogress">
            <CircularProgress color="secondary" />
          </div>
        )}
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </CardDeck>
    </Row>
    
                       
)

}
```

I don't know if this implementation is optimal